# Is it possible to stitch together 2 or more large canvas to get 1 image blob?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html2canvas

Our app has some "Save as Image" functionality, which will take a chart (rendered with plain HTML) and export it as image. To do this we firstly use a library called html2canvas to convert the HTML to a canvas, then we use canvas to convert to Image to download.

The problem is the user is able to expand nodes in the chart, and so the chart can get bigger and bigger, currently we don't limit how big the chart can expand. At a certain point the chart becomes too big, and the canvas will no longer be able to function due to pixel limits in the HTML5 Canvas. We show them an error message if they try to do this.

Here is my question - I wonder if I could increase the limit by using multiple canvas objects, by using a DIV around the chart with `overflow: hidden` I could export multiple times in a grid. Now I have 2 or more large HTML5 Canvas objects, and I want to stitch them together to one large image.

```
// Just to show how to do one canvas
function exportCanvasToImage(canvas, fileName) {
  canvas.toBlob(b => saveAs(b, fileName));
}
/**
 * @param {Array.<Array>} canvasGrid 2D array of Canvas to stitch together
 * @param {String} fileName The name of file to write, i.e. "test.jpg"
 */
function exportLargeCanvasGridToImage(canvasGrid, fileName) {
  // is this possible?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the content of one canvas inside another using `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()` and you can turn a canvas into a data URL using `HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()`.
So what you're trying should theoretically be possible, but I doubt that you can use this approach to overcome technical limitations of the canvas API.

Comment: I won't be able to use this approach, if I could then I would rather use just one canvas to begin with rather than splitting it up to multiple Canvas objects.